# Use PHP on Google App Engine root directory yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

What `app.yaml` file do I need to be able to upload `default.php`, `page1.php`, etc. without defining every file in `app.yaml`? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently updated documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig:

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Will serve all php scripts.